# Checking null position using RandomAccessFile

Tags: java, null, eof, randomaccessfile

I need to check if a position in a random access file has not been written to. The problem with this is, when the position *actually* hasn't been written to, I get (as anticipated) an EOFException. I have been reading RandomAccessFile documentation to try to solve this problem, and tried researching online.

### Things I've tried:

- Using a try-catch block and catching every time there is a EOFException (Using try-catch as a conditional statement). It works, but it is horrible practice, and it is very inefficient, as for my case it is EOF the majority of the time.
- Using a BufferReader to loop through and check the position. I ended up running into many problems and decided that there must be a better way.

I don't want to do any copying one file over to another or any other work around. I know there has to be a direct way of doing this, I just can't seem to find the correct solution.

Comment: The position must be a number which cannot be `null` can you show us some code which gives you a "null"?

Comment: When I seek to a position that contains nothing and I try to read the position, I get an EOFException. Sorry, I should probably re-word my question.

Comment: So I would use the FileChannel.length() to check the data you want exists before you seek it.  You don't need to keep checking it if you assume it doesn't get any smaller.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to write a "tailer"?

What you need to do is have one thread which reads only the data which is there using FileChannel.size() to check for more data.  This data is passed to a piped input.  This allows you to have a second thread which reads the piped stream continuously e.g. using BufferedReader and blocks where more data is needed.

Comment: Are you sure it's not FileChannel.size()?

Comment: @DillonBurton Right it is `File.length()` I was confusing with.  I suggest avoiding File.length as it creates quite a bit of garbage.